# How to Deserialize a string which contains multiple object of same type in appended format [C#]

Tags: c#, serialization, json-deserialization, multiple-instances, jsonreader

Let's say I have an Employee class.

```
Employee
{
   string Name;
   int Age
}
```

My string contains the data of different company's employee in a string. I want deserialize it as List of Company Info. I have Company Class. Is there any solution which can deserialize multiple appended objects represented as string as following .

```
[{"companyName":"ABC","Employees":[{"Name":"X","Age":24},{"Name":"Y","Age":27}]}]
[{"companyName":"XYZ","Employees":[{"Name":"A","Age":24},{"Name":"B","Age":27}]}]
```

I want to know If there is an existing solution for it or I need to write my own JSON reader.

Comment: What you've shown isn't valid Json. If it were, you could just use the built-in .NET deserialiser. If that's really the pseudo-Json you've been given, you can either fix it to be valid, or split it down into individual Json chunks and deserialise each one in turn.

Comment: yes, It's not a valid json. I'm looking if there is some existing solution which can parse it and deserialize it as valid json object.

Answer (score 0):

Given the sample you have shown, it is pretty easy to convert to valid Json. You need to replace the `]` at the end of the first (and subsequent, but not including the last) lines with a comma, and remove the `[` at the beginning of all lines other than the first, eg...

```json
[{"companyName":"ABC","Employees":[{"Name":"X","Age":24},{"Name":"Y","Age":27}]},
{"companyName":"XYZ","Employees":[{"Name":"A","Age":24},{"Name":"B","Age":27}]}]
```

That is then valid Json that can be parsed by any standard parser.